Can you use defineString() etc helper methods to define environment variables in Cloud Run Jobs
Can you use defineString() etc helper methods to define environment variables in Cloud Run Jobs.
Currently they are part of firebase-functions package
import {defineBoolean, defineInt, defineSecret, defineString} from "firebase-functions/params";

export const projectIdKey = defineString("PROJECT_ID");

Would something like this be possible in Cloud Run Jobs

I don't think Cloud Run Doesn't support any such libraries. Either you have to use console or command line to Set environment variables
